# Average Volume Every Weekday In a Month Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to calculate an expression in Tableau 10.2 for a contact center use case.
I have calls at every hour all days of the week.
I need to calculate the average call per hour per day. For instance i need to calculate the average call every Sunday at 9 pm and use that in tool tip. 
By this i am measuring how many average calls we get on a given Sunday or any other day of the week at a particular hour.
I had written an expression sadly that is not resulting in accurate number

```
AVG({ FIXED [Weekday Flagging],[Hour]:
AVG([Volume])})
```

Do suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very Recently I had a same requirement to see avg visitors on the hours of all the days of a week. My requirement was (Total No. Of Visitors on Sundays/No.Of Sundays) and then (Total No of Visitors @hour/No. Of Sundays).

1)create a calculated field : sum(volume)/countd(date) and name it 'Avg Volume'

2)drag date to 'Columns'. From the drop down click 'More' -> 'Weekday'

3)drag the calculated field to rows. This will give avg volume on each days of a week.

To get Avg Volume of hours

1)do the same procedure as above and instead of 'Weekday', drag Hour of the day to the column.

Link these 2 sheets using an action filter, so that if u click on sunday in the first sheet, it will show the avg volume of each hour of sunday in the second sheet.

Comment: Appreciate your assistance Maria this helped.